# Access parent from child within array using Parse.com

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I have a `Game` class and a `Round`class. Game has a column named `rounds` which is an array of `Round` objects.

As there is a small and limited amount of them I chose `Array` over `Parse.Relation`, which I consider easy to use.

I have a `Round` object and I want to access the `Game`which is his parent object.

How do I achieve that ?

Comment: You mention PFRelation, but your tags say javascript.

Are you looking for code for cloud code or iOS client? PFRelation is the iOS equivalent of the javascript API's Parse.Relation

Comment: I see you marked my answer as correct - did it work with an array of a single pointer, or did you have to pass an array of the objectId? I want to edit my answer so that it is clear for anyone who stumbled across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the javascript API, I would use the Parse.Query.containsAll method.

This method takes two parameters, the key (field name) that must contain the object(s), and an array of values (in this case, the array will only contain one value.

```
var gameQuery = new Parse.Query("Game");
gameQuery.containsAll("rounds", [ round ]);
gameQuery.first().then
(
    function( game )
    {
        //do stuff
    }
);
```

I've never actually used this method for an array of pointers, though. you may need to pass an array containing just the object id of the round, rather than the pointer to the round. I'm not sure.